# I can't access Google Console API

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm currently working on android project using google maps API. But i can't seem to access my google console API. 
Everytime i used the link provided by the android studio.it always ended as a blank white page.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

[Click here to go to console page](http://console.developers.google.com). It will ask you to sign in first in case you are not signed in. After that you have to create a new project there and have to specify which API you are going to use.